# The keyboad hook dll can't work well

Tags: winapi, keyboard, hook

The code of `keyhook.cpp` in dll:

```
// KeyHook.cpp : 定义 DLL 应用程序的导出函数。
//
#include "stdafx.h"

#include "stdio.h"
#include "Windows.h"
#pragma comment(linker, "/SECTION:.SHARED,RWS")
#pragma data_seg(".SHARED")
#define DEF_PROCESS_NAME "notepad.exe"

HINSTANCE g_hInstance = NULL;
HHOOK g_hHook = NULL;

HWND g_hWnd = NULL;
#pragma data_seg()
BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HINSTANCE hModule,DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,LPVOID        lpReserved)
{
    printf("main function in dll\n");
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        g_hInstance = hModule;  
        printf("max=%d\n", MAX_PATH);
        break;
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}


LRESULT CALLBACK KeyboardProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{

//OutputDebugString("what the hell\n");
    char szPath[MAX_PATH] = { 0, };
    char *p = NULL;
//printf("the callback function");
    int shift = nCode;
    if (shift = 0) 
    {

        if (!(lParam & 0x80000000))
        {
            GetModuleFileNameA(NULL, szPath, MAX_PATH);
            p = strrchr(szPath, '\\');
        //printf("szPath=%s\n", szPath);
            OutputDebugString("what the hell\n");
            if (!_stricmp(p + 1, DEF_PROCESS_NAME))
                return 1;
        }
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(g_hHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif // DEBUG

    __declspec(dllexport) void HookStart()
    {
        printf("hookstart function\n");
        g_hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD, KeyboardProc, g_hInstance, 0);
        if (g_hHook == NULL)
            printf("failed to install the keyboard hook");
        else
        {
            printf("Succeed in installing the keyboard hook");
        }

    }

    __declspec(dllexport) void HookStop()
    {
        if (g_hHook)
        {
            UnhookWindowsHookEx(g_hHook);
            g_hHook = NULL;
        }
        printf("hookstop function\n");
    }
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif // DEBUG
```

The calling application code:

```
// hkeybi.cpp : 定义控制台应用程序的入口点。

#include "stdafx.h"
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<Windows.h> 

#define DEF_DLL_NAME "KeyHook.dll"
#define DEF_HOOKSTART "HookStart"
#define DEF_HOOKSTOP "HookStop"

typedef void(*PFN_HOOKSTART)();
typedef void(*PFN_HOOKSTOP)();

int main()
{
    int ch = -1;
    HMODULE hDll = NULL;
    PFN_HOOKSTART HookStart = NULL;
    PFN_HOOKSTOP HookStop = NULL;

    hDll = LoadLibraryA(DEF_DLL_NAME);
    HookStart = (PFN_HOOKSTART)GetProcAddress(hDll, DEF_HOOKSTART);
    HookStop = (PFN_HOOKSTOP)GetProcAddress(hDll, DEF_HOOKSTOP);
    if ((HookStart != NULL) && (HookStop != NULL))
        printf("hello start\n");
    HookStart();

    printf("press q to exit!\n");
    while (_getch() != 'q');

    HookStop();

    FreeLibrary(hDll);
    return 0;
}
```

When I run the app,after I input several words,it will go down. I spent long time in solving the problem.

Comment: the pre tags and “enter code here” are not included.Please just ignore them

Comment: What app is crashing? Notepad or your hook installer? When hook is installed and its dll is loaded in the process address space you could attach to it with your debugger and see where exactly is a problem.

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems in your KeyboardProc function. The first one being that your `shift` variable is assigned instead of tested:

```
if (shift = 0)
```

The variable is assigned 0, the condition is therefore always false. Effectively, the only code executed after the test is the `return CallNextHookEx(...)`. If the condition would be true, you may run into problems because the `GetModuleFileNameA` result is not tested. In case of an error, the following strrchr will likely fail and the `p` pointer will be `NULL`. This will result in a crash at the `_stricmp`. And why do you specifically use the ANSI version of `GetModuleFileName`, are you sure you're not using Unicode? Finally, returning the hook proc without calling `CallNextHookEx` is a bad idea. Here's what the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644984.aspx) says:

> If code is greater than or equal to zero, and the hook procedure did
>   not process the message, it is highly recommended that you call
>   CallNextHookEx and return the value it returns

Comment: Given the Unicode in the OP's code block, your Unicode suggestion is probably a safe bet, and something that they should be doing anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.　Even the procedure is not executed.The dll can't work well.It will become dead after I input several words .And then I add the message loop code . It will work fluently but the functionality doesn't work.